# Sum Formula Crystal Reports Inquiry

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Ok, say I have a subreport that populates a chart I have from data in a table. I have a summary sum field that adds up the total of each row displayed. I am about to add two new rows that need to be displayed but not totaled up in the sum. There is a field in the table that has a number from 1-7 in it. If I added these new fields into the database, I would assign a negative number to this like -1 and -2 to differentiate it between the other records. How can I set up a formula so that it will sum up all of the amount fields except for the records that have an 'order' number we will call it of either -1 or -2? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Running Total Field and set the evaluate formula to something like `{new_field} >= 0`. So it will only sum the value when it passes that test.

Comment: Ok, I have one other question which I figured I might as well ask here instead of doing a new thread...Is there any way to set up a formula to display a value depending on the value in another field? Say if new_field = -1 then display info in new_field2 of that data row? How would a formula for that work? I've tried it now with doing a formula for if{table.order} = 3 then {table.value} but it is just showing 0.0 each time while the value is showing up normally with the other records above.

Comment: yea, just create a formula field like you described and add it to the report. You'd need to supply a default value for the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

The way to accomplish this without a running total is with a formula like this:

```
if {OrderNum} >= 0 Then {Amount}
```